# sceneKit и все - таки... почему так получается =?

Tags: swift

-game проект из темплайта Xcode
-в стандартную сцену из Object library Xcode добавлена Geosphere

-вопрос = почему на экране при запуске проекта на выполнение наблюдается овал типа дыня при размещении объекта в углу экрана= ? (при размещении объекта по центру изображение нормальное в виде окружности)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]